# How to copy changed format of date to another column in same table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064, sql-date-functions

I've got one table with two columns, one `timestamp` with timestamp and second with `date` in '%Y-%m-%d' format.
I need to get timestamp from `timestamp` column, convert it to '%Y-%m-%d' and put it into `date` column.
So when I did like this:

```
UPDATE
  `table_name`
SET
  `date` = DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`),
    '%Y-%m-%d'
  )
;
```

then I've got an error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM `table_name` WHERE 1 AND (`date` <> DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`' at line 1
```

How to do it right?

Comment: The error message doesn't belong to the update statement shown. (The message talks about an error close to "FROM table_name", which doesn't exist in your statement, so it must be another query the message is referring to.)

Comment: Answer is:
UPDATE
  `table_name`
SET
  `date` = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`))
;